# Excel formula to sum the range of two numbers in parenthesis?

Tags: progressdialog, date-arithmetic

In one cell I have this text.
S231109F So-Geo 2XGX01 Santa-Fe-Springs 2Full (117;118)-

In another cell on the same row, I typically type in the difference of the numbers within the parenthesis. In this case I would type in "2".  Is there an excel formula that would read the range within the parenthesis and automatically calculate the difference so I don't have to do the math myself?

I found a function that may work but I don't know how to change it due to brain fog.
=MID(B5,SEARCH("(",B5)+1,SEARCH(")",B5)-SEARCH("(",B5)-1)+0